# adding gridview in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to add GRIDVIEW etc in MVC3 using Razor syntax in asp.net (c#)? like web forms, if not then how to display large amount of data. One can not make manual tables etc like php etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well you'd normally iterate through your data, something like:

```
@model MyWebApp.SearchViewModel
<table>
    @foreach (var result in Model.Results) {
        <tr><td>@result.Id</td><td>@result.Title</td></tr>
    }
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To display tables with lots of data, I use [DataTables plugin](http://www.ajaxshake.com/plugin/EN/982/323715d4/easy-jquery-table-jquery-datatables.html). It allows you to load data page by page (using ajax). [Here is an example](http://www.datatables.net/development/server-side/asp_ne) implementation of the server side.
[(How should look the json answer)](http://www.datatables.net/usage/server-side)

[image: DataTables plugin]t